# How do you render a jQuery object with underscore template

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I was wondering how I can render a jQuery object with _.template.

```
$(function(){
    var $el = $('p');
    $el.html('Hello');

    var context = {
        'elem' : $el
    }

    var tmpl = $('#tmpl').html();
    var result = _.template(tmpl)(context);

    $('div').html(result);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bDVeV/

This returns [object Object]. I read to get the outer html you can do $el[0].outerHTML but then I lose my click event it seems.

Answer (score 0):

$el is an object, not a string, so you have to get the data into json format. 
This will work:

```
var context = {
        'elem' : $el.html()
    }
```

and don't forget to bind the click event after the p tag is inserted into the DOM

Comment: This will only put in 'Hello' and not '<p>Hello</p>'.

Comment: ok, assuming this is a contrived example and that you solved your problem using outterHTML already. The solution would be to bind your click event *after* you add your template to the DOM.